# What's better to use in joomla, modules or conditional statements to check page

Tags: javascript, html, joomla, module

I wonder what is the best way to display different parts of a template on different pages,

1. Using modules, for instance

`<jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-1" style="xhtml" />`

or

1. Conditional statements to check what page on, for instance

`if ($menu->getActive() == $menu->getDefault()):`

When I say best, I mean, with what method do you get the best performance, best support in browsers (and versions) and is most secure to use. Right now in my site, I am using a module called custom html advanced to introduce javascript in certain places. And I am using conditional statements to display different code on different places, but it is best to be consistent when possible and so I wonder which is the best way.

**EDIT:**

I might add that my code already contains conditional statements to allow for different page structures, so it looks something like this

```
if page-1

HTML stuff for page 1...

elseif page-2

HTML stuff for page 2...

elseif page-3

HTML stuff for page 3...
```

So maybe it's better to paste my javascript/html code directly into the conditional statements because it will be faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to use modules and create the needed positions in the template.

**Reasons:**

1. It makes the website easy maintainable and customisable. For example if you want to remove something it would be much easier to disable the module than diving in your template code.
2. If you have a lot of "options" it would be a mess of if/else statements.
3. The conditional statements are not noob friendly.

The support for browsers or the security of both methods depends on what you're putting in your code/module.

Comment: My page has a slider(uses javascript) and some thumbnails(only html + css) using, and originally I was implementing them as modules using the aforementioned module, but it became quite cumbersome having to go and change in the back-end of joomla everytime I needed to change something, so I pulled them out directly into the code because I have conditional statements anyway because I need a different structure for each page (I have 3 different page structures). I will probably then put them back as modules when the coding is done to make it more maintainable and customisable upon later changes.

Comment: Something just hit me, If I'm already using conditional statements for different page structures, then wouldn't it be best to have the code directly inside the html page? Because joomla is probably itself using some conditional statements, albeit more optimized, so instead of doing it twice, isn't it better to just do it once?

Comment: @jedanput: yes it would be faster to just host the js into your main template file, but as HamZa said, it's just for mantainability. Having separate modules in the backend means an extra row returned by the sql statement, that has to be parsed, i.e. on a normal server the difference would be lower than 0.1ms, and not even that if you're using proper caching! So don't worry about performance in this case, just maintainability, ask yourself the question: will anybody be able to understand this? will I be able to understand it 2 years from now?